# Google Sheet Query outputting value into wrong row

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to consolidate some data and running into a bizarre issue. I am using a query function that is working perfectly in some instances but not in other. When referencing a particular sheet, it keeps outputting the values in the row beneath, which is causing aa #REF error.

[Here is a copy of the Google Sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fU1KNI119kD6P9vw1iA0WWuT45o0lgmqYf3NC1VVAcU/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the formula I'm using (which again, works perfectly sometimes, but not when pulling data from certain sheets)

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT($B125&"!$A$2:$1000"), "SELECT E WHERE A = date '"& text($C125, "yyyy-mm-dd") &"' and B contains '"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($E125, " " , ""),"AM", ""), "PM", "")&"' ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the number of headers otherwise it will try to guess which eventually results in rows being magically merged into the header causing all sorts of unpredictable behavior:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT($B125&"!$A$2:$1000"), "SELECT E WHERE A = date '"& text($C125, "yyyy-mm-dd") &"' and B contains '"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($E125, " " , ""),"AM", ""), "PM", "")&"' ",1)
```

All I did was add a `,1` just before the closing parenthesis so that it specifies always 1 row of headers. The format of your data is really messed up and you need to think about cleaning up your data.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very new to data, so would love any advice you have on what we're doing wrong :)

Comment: @GeoffSchultz Basically try to keep your data as raw as possible and then create a report the way you like it. Also all the data looks like it could be on one sheet instead of multiple sheets if it was organized in a more database like format. It doesn't really matter if this sheet already does what you want it to do but if you want to make major changes it's just not easy.